# How to get WorkManager always running in background

Tags: java, android, workmanagers, android-workmanager

How do i get WorkManager always running in background, nomatter if app is closed/killed/open, it should always be running. I've code in `doWork` method that checks for changes in database and sends a notification upon change in database. So, it should always be running in bg to check for changes.
So what should i be using for this, `OneTimeRequest` or `PeriodicWorkRequest`? Also, in my Worker class I've Result set to `RETRY` i.e. `return Result.RETRY;` ,in a hope to keep it always running. 
PS- I don't want WorkManager to go idle in any state/condition. What should be the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

> How do i get WorkManager always running in background, nomatter if app is closed/killed/open, it should always be running

You don't. That is not how `WorkManager` operates. It uses `JobScheduler` to process work when your app is not otherwise running, and `JobScheduler` jobs do not run continuously.

The only thing that vaguely resembles what you want is to use a foreground service.

Comment: Do you mean that, Work Manager will not able to automatically executed in system background without manually trigger it. However, once it got trigger from the Apps, then I will just run one-time execution until the Job is done even the Apps is closed/killed?

Comment: @IamaStudent: "Work Manager will not able to automatically executed in system background without manually trigger it" -- already-scheduled periodic work will happen automatically, but the period is fairly coarse-grained (15 minutes minimum).

Comment: @CommonsWare ,yes that's what i'm asking..how do i check status of running work and if it's not running, how do i make it run?

Comment: @Mukesh work manager wont do what you want you should use a service that will be loaded with the system - otherwise you can schedule a job using the manger and have that worker check the changes etc then when done schedule another job and so on (not a recommended method unless you need to check for changes every 15 minutes or so)